# 'Text format field is required' error when saving Better Exposed filters (BEF)

Tags: entities, views

For one of the views exposed filters I'm using BEF but when I'm trying to save one of the filters as checkboxes/radio buttons it give me below error. I've no clue to what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Text format field is required]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

Navigate to the BEF settings under the view in question (like the screenshot above).

Scroll down to  **Require input before results are shown**, select the checkbox, there should be a "Text on demand" field.

Set the Text format field to one a valid text format.

Then apply the changes.

I created a video tutorial for you to follow: http://recordit.co/V75Zl4gAAl